# mysql sql, obtener el jugador con más votos por posición

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo esta tabla con estos dos campos. Necesito sacar el máximo de votos y el id del jugador por posición:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He utilizado esta query para sacar los totales, pero no se como sacar el total máximo por posición

```
select idJugador,posicion, count(idJugador) as total 
     from table
        group by idJugador, posicion order by posicion
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: a que te refieres al total maximo por posicion? a que le llamas votos?

Comment: puedes mostrar algo de lo que quieres ver? no queda claro..

Comment: por ejemplo, para la posición 1 el idJugador 164 es el que más votos tiene con 5, sería evitar sacar los otros dos registros con solamente 1 voto y lo mismo para el resto de posiciones.

Comment: cada registro de la tabla contabiliza como un voto. Lo que hago es contar el mismo idJugador por posición, por ejemplo el idJugador 164 se repite 5 veces, por lo tanto, son 5 votos. Lo que quiero obtener sería: [164|1|5] [160|2|4] [165|3|2] [158|3|2]

Comment: porque no intentas con un procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: @mark te recomiendo mucho leer [ask] y del mismo modo hacer el [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Usamos *subconsultas*, tomando como base tu ultimo *query* y solo restaría hacerle un **group by** adicionando la clausula **MAX()**

```
   SELECT
           T2.posicion,
           T2.totalMax,
           T3.idJugador
   FROM
     (
     SELECT 
                T1.posicion,
                MAX(T1.total) as totalMax
        FROM (
             SELECT
                idJugador,
                posicion,
                count(idJugador) as total 
             FROM table
                group by 
                   idJugador,
                   posicion
                order by posicion
            ) AS T1
      GROUP BY 
        T1.posicion
    ) AS T2
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        idJugador,
        posicion, 
        count(idJugador) as total 
     FROM table
     GROUP BY 
        idJugador, 
        posicion
) AS T3
```

ON T2.totalMax = T3.total AND T2.posicion = T3.posicion

Con esto tendrías, el máximo de los totales, junto al id del jugador asociado y su numero de posición.

Acá tenes mas info de las tablas derivadas.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html

Comment: esa query no logra el objetivo solicitado.

Comment: Esta solicitando el  máximo de los totales, junto al id del jugador asociado y su numero de posición, esto es justamente lo que devuelve,¿ o hay algo que no estoy viendo ?

Comment: la query solo debe retornar 1 valor de cada posicion. por ej: en la posicion 1 tienes 164,756,550. solo debe retornar 164 porque tiene mayor votos

Comment: Es verdad, el group by esta con ambos parametros

Answer (score 0):

listo, prueba con esta query, ami me corre ok en  mi local:

```
 select * from(
 select idjugador,posicion,count(posicion) as votos  from test.juego  group by 
 idjugador order by posicion)
 x  group by x.posicion
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me saca correctamente los datos, en mi base de datos, el IdJugador 708 solo tiene un registro y me sale como si tuviera dos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que me sale es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @mark si probaste la respuesta de Francisco y no te resulto, no modifiques su respuesta; usa la zona de comentarios justo debajo y comentale por que así solo se van a confundir entre los 2

Answer (score 0):

Con SQL bien plano puedes plantear la solución como una combinación de subconsultas:

1. Con tu consulta obtenemos la cantidad de votos para cada `posicion` y `idJugador`
2. Luego solo nos falta saber cual es el máximo de votos en cada posición y juntando ambas consultas filtraremos únicamente los jugadores cuya cantidad de votos coincida con el máximo para cada posición.

Esto tiene una tema, que tampoco has definido como resolverlo, y es cuando eventualmente dos jugadores tienen la misma cantidad (máxima) de votos en una posición, esta solución te retornará los dos.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT  idJugador,
        posicion, 
        COUNT(idJugador) as total 
        FROM table
        GROUP BY idJugador, posicion
)
SELECT  T1.posicion,
        T1.idJugador,
        T1.total
        FROM CTE T1
        INNER JOIN (SELECT  posicion
                            MAX(total) as MaxTotal
                            FROM CTE
                            GROUP BY posicion
        ) T2
        ON T1.posicion = T2.Posicion
        AND T1.total = T2.MaxTotal
        ORDER BY T1.posicion
```

Observaciones:

- Estamos usando una [common table expresion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), es más cómodo pero eventualmente se podría resolver con subconsultas comunes.
- Ten en cuenta que no tengo datos como para probarlo, se me pudo haber escapado algo

Por las dudas, como veo por los comentarios que tal vez tengas una versión de MySql anterior a la 8.0, está es la versión sin CTE, no es muy distinta solo un poco más larga.

```
 SELECT  T1.posicion,
        T1.idJugador,
        T1.total
        FROM (SELECT    idJugador,
                        posicion, 
                        COUNT(idJugador) as total 
                        FROM tabla
                        GROUP BY idJugador, posicion
        ) T1
        INNER JOIN (SELECT  posicion,
                            MAX(total) as MaxTotal
                            FROM (SELECT    idJugador,
                                            posicion, 
                                            COUNT(idJugador) as total 
                                            FROM tabla
                                            GROUP BY idJugador, posicion
                            ) T3
                            GROUP BY posicion
        ) T2
        ON T1.posicion = T2.Posicion
        AND T1.total = T2.MaxTotal
        ORDER BY T1.posicion
        ;
```

Comment: :o desde cuando podemos usar cte en mysql!!??. ya regreso tengo que modificar algunas query´s

Comment: @LucianoMontañez desde la versión 8

Comment: me arroja error de sintaxis en la linea 1

Comment: que versión de mysql tienes @FranciscoAcevedo ?

Comment: 6, debe ser por eso

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo no existe versión 6 de MySQL

Comment: actualice 8.0 tenia 6.3

Comment: muchas gracias,estoy probando un xampp con mysql en versión 5, pero lo probaré en una versión 8, un saludo.

Comment: @mark, edité la respuesta agregando la versión sin usar CTE, que debiera ser compatible con tu versión . Saludos.

Comment: Me salta el siguiente error -> Cada tabla derivada debe tener su propio alias

Comment: Es cierto, faltaba un alias, acabo de modificar el código, revisalo.

Comment: las versiones 6 y 7 son la cluster, las comunity pasan de 5.7 a 8

Comment: Si, funciona correctamente, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Usando tablas auxiliares t1 en el from y t2 en el where (filtra las posiciones con su maximo puntaje):

```
select idJugador, posicion, total
 from 
    ( select idJugador, posicion, count(idJugador) as total 
      from CTE
      group by idJugador, posicion 
      order by posicion
    ) t1
where ( posicion, total) in   ( 
        select posicion, max(total) 
           from (
               select idJugador, posicion, count(idJugador) as total 
                 from CTE
                 group by idJugador, posicion 
                 order by posicion
                ) t2
        group by 1 
        )
 order by posicion, idJugador desc
```

[Link de prueba](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc7651/17)

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, funciona correctamente.

Comment: @mark, y podrias marcar como respuesta valida.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(posicion) as votos, jugador from tu_tabla order by votos desc group by votos, jugador.
```